# How can i align contents of my print page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

[This is the print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEET0.jpg)I'm using a javascript function to print a page. But the print preview is having alignment mistakes and I've tried
both using link tag
and also @media print. Both are not working for me.
Any and all help would be great.Thankyou.

```
function ClickHereToPrint() {
    try {
        var printContent = document.getElementById('divToPrint').innerHTML;
        var windowUrl = 'about:blank';
        var uniqueName = new Date();
        var windowName = 'Print' + uniqueName.getTime();
        var printWindow = window.open(windowUrl, windowName, 'left=50000,top=50000,width=0,height=0');
        printWindow.document.write(printContent);
        printWindow.document.close();
        printWindow.focus();
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }
    catch (e) {
        self.print();
    }
}

<div id="divToPrint">
    <div class="imgcontainer">
    <img align="left" hspace="15" src="Dotline/images/neridioLogo.png" alt="Edit" height="150" width="150">
      <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <h6 align="center"><b>Migrated Files</b></h6>
    <p align="center"> hell0.txt </p>
    <p align="center"> hell0.txt </p>
    <h6 align="center"><b>Failed Files</b></h6>
    <p align="center"> failed.txt </p>
    <p align="center"> failed.txt </p>
</div>
```

Comment: What are the alignment mistakes? What does your media query contain?

Comment: Note that the `align` attribute is depreciated and "[should no longer be used](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Deprecated_attributes)". I recommend using a CSS property like [`float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) or some other layout method like [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox).

Comment: I've added an image in the question for your reference

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to achieve the desired layout using HTML and CSS.

Here's one way using `display:inline-block`:

```css
.image,
.text {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.image {
  margin: 0 2em 0 0;
}

.close {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}

.text h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="divToPrint">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" alt="Edit" height="150" width="150">
    <span class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h6>Migrated Files</h6>
    <p>hell0.txt</p>
    <p>hell0.txt</p>
    <h6>Failed Files</h6>
    <p>failed.txt</p>
    <p>failed.txt</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's another way using [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox):

```css
#divToPrint {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.image {
  margin: 0 2em 0 0;
}

.close {
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 0 0 0.5em;
}

.text h6 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="divToPrint">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/150/150" alt="Edit" height="150" width="150">
    <span class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    <h6>Migrated Files</h6>
    <p>hell0.txt</p>
    <p>hell0.txt</p>
    <h6>Failed Files</h6>
    <p>failed.txt</p>
    <p>failed.txt</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

For reference, see [Learn to style HTML using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS).

Answer (score 0):

It is because of image you used on the left side, and the element first `<h6>` and `<p>` tag takes the position of the center after that logo image if you want to align it, you have to give padding or margin to both `<h6>` and `<p>` element